# Handling LostFocus and Deactivate events

Tags: .net, wpf

I have this code attached to `LostFocus` and `Deactivate` events:

```
    private void Window_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { }
    }
```

Weird blank `catch` is caused the fact, that if I close (by pressing `X`) the window it also raises `Deactivate` even so in this case I'm trying to close already closing window. Is there any better way to handle it?

To be more clear, my scenario is: I have a window that needed to be closed on lostfocus, deactivation and closing with regular `X` or `Alt+f4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option (besides having an `IsClosing` state) is to attach to the closing event and unsubscribe from the deactivated and lost focus events to prevent them from being called:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Deactivated -= Window_Deactivated;
    LostFocus -= Window_LostFocus;
}
```

Comment: Is it 100% conditional race -safe solution?

Comment: Event handlers are called synchroneously and in addition to to that this one should be only called on the UI thread. So unless you do some nasty stuff from background threads to your window this should be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
bool IsClosing = false;
private void Window_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CloseWindow();
}

private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseWindow();
}

void CloseWindow()
{
    if (IsClosing == false)
    {
        IsClosing = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, thought about this too, but a dirty hack too.